# Change or set an advertise address in Microk8s

Tags: microk8s

I am creating a cluster in MicroK8s, however when using Kubernetes I am able to specify an API Server Advertise Address that I can use to join my cluster. I need that functionality in MicroK8s, however I haven't found a way that works.

Thus far I have modified the file at `/var/snap/microk8s/current/certs/csr.conf` with a new ip `IP.5 MYIPV6` whilst also modifying the output of `microk8s.kubectl config view --raw`and using it in as the KubeConfig. Nothing has worked.

In general terms, I want to expose a public IPV6 Address so worker nodes can join my cluster.

Comment: Did you try https://microk8s.io/docs/services-and-ports